# C# CustomButton doesn't work CancelButton and AcceptButton

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, button, user-controls

I make my own CustomButton.

```
public partial class CustomButton : Button
{
    public Image Background_Hover { get; set; }
    public Image Background_Down { get; set; }
    public Image Background_Normal;

    public Image Image_Hover { get; set; }
    public Image Image_Down { get; set; }
    public Image Image_Normal;

    public Color ForeColor_Hover { get; set; }
    public Color ForeColor_Down { get; set; }
    public Color ForeColor_Normal;

    public CustomButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseEnter(System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Background_Normal = base.BackgroundImage;
        if (Background_Hover != null) base.BackgroundImage = Background_Hover;

        Image_Normal = base.Image;
        if (Image_Hover != null) base.Image = Image_Hover;

        ForeColor_Normal = base.ForeColor;
        if (ForeColor_Hover != Color.Empty) base.ForeColor = ForeColor_Hover;

        base.OnMouseEnter(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeave(System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Background_Hover != null) base.BackgroundImage = Background_Normal;
        if (Image_Hover != null) base.Image = Image_Normal;
        if (ForeColor_Hover != Color.Empty) base.ForeColor = ForeColor_Normal;

        base.OnMouseLeave(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Background_Down != null) base.BackgroundImage = Background_Down;
        if (Image_Down != null) base.Image = Image_Down;
        if (ForeColor_Down != Color.Empty) base.ForeColor = ForeColor_Down;

        base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Background_Hover != null) base.BackgroundImage = Background_Hover;
        if (Image_Hover != null) base.Image = Image_Hover;
        if (ForeColor_Hover != Color.Empty) base.ForeColor = ForeColor_Hover;

        base.OnMouseUp(e);
    }       
}
```

And I make login form, so I want login form close when user input Enter or ESC.

So I add CustomButton and assign CustomButton on login form AcceptButton and Cancel Button property.

But It doesn't work and even the click event does not occure when I input Enter or ESC.

I don't know why it doesn't work.

Because I make CustomButton inherited System.Windows.Forms.Button.

I think it work like System.Windows.Forms.Button, but it isn't.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Your code works fine here. Did you code the clicked event??

Comment: As TaW said, add the `Button.Click()` handler. This even will be raised when you click on the Button or press `ESC` and it the Form's `CancelButton` or press `ENTER` and it's the Form's `AcceptButton` or the Button has focus.